# How to process string stream of badly delimited data?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tcplistener, networkstream

I'm faced with a third party integration that send's serial data over TCP to my TCP Listener written in async C#. The issu I have is how to process (delimite) recived data, since there is no obvius delimiter or something that would allow easy processing.

This device sends data:

```
CAT 0 RESTART\r\n
PANEL RESTART                           DIG.IP              14:41:35  06-Nov-20\r\n
                                                                               \r\n
HEARTBEAT\r\n
CAT 4\r\n
NO RESPONSE         Zone 000    A002    460P                14:42:29  06-Nov-20\r\n
                    .                   Sistem              Opticni            \r\n
CAT 4\r\n
NO RESPONSE         Zone 000    A001    420CPi              14:42:29  06-Nov-20\r\n
                    .                   Sistem              Rocni javlj        \r\n
HEARTBEAT\r\n
HEARTBEAT\r\n
HEARTBEAT\r\n
CAT 0\r\n
USER LOG ON         Zone 000       U099 DIG.IP              14:44:18  06-Nov-20\r\n
                    .                   Sistem              User Access        \r\n
```

Each event data starts with "CAT" and hase 3 lines of data. First line is variable length, seccond and third line are both 80 characters long.
There is also HEARTBEAT that is one line only.

How would you process this data?

Comment: Is your problem how to process TCP, or how to process a string stream?

Comment: How to process string stream. Thank you.

Comment: Then you should separate your problem. As stated, you have a lot of boilerplate that won't let anyone to help you; you should write a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'd create a function that accepts a `StreamReader` as an input and use it to process the events.  But these kind of questions ("How can I do this?") are not accepted here in StackOverflow, and you'll get your question closed. Write some code first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should separate the values by \r\n in order to get single lines.
Then you can separate each line by space symbol " " and get words. Then you can take needed words from the array. You can use `String.Split` method for splitting the strings.

Answer (score 0):

The data, as posted, appears to be fixed-width, not delimited. Also, it appears that the format of each line is determined by the first "word", such as "HEARTBEAT\r\n". So, your code must first read a line, then read the first 20 characters (according to the data you posted), trim that, and then do a switch or a series of if() statements to decide what the format is for the rest of the line. Something like this:

```
public void test(string data)
{
    foreach (string s in data.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    {
        string line = s;
        switch (s.PadRight(20).Substring(0, 20).Trim())//pad in case entire line is shorter than 20 chars
        {
            case "NO RESPONSE":
                ParseNO_RESPONSE(s);
                break;
            case "CAT 0 RESTART":
                //ParseCAT_0_RESTART(s);
                break;
            //case ....
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
private void ParseNO_RESPONSE(string message)
{
    //message = "NO RESPONSE         Zone 000    A002    460P                14:42:29  06-Nov-20";
    string sCol1 = message.Substring(0, 20).Trim();
    string sCol2 = message.Substring(20, 12).Trim();
    string sCol3 = message.Substring(32, 8).Trim();
    string sCol4 = message.Substring(40, 20).Trim();
    string sCol5 = message.Substring(60, message.Length - 60).Trim();
    //do stuff with the data here
}
```